How to find there are 570 banks in the list using Playwright
I'm trying to automate that there are 570 banks in the list using Playwright - Java in this website: https://www.fdic.gov/bank-failures/failed-bank-list
So far, I wrote:
Playwright playwright = Playwright.create();
        Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(false));
        BrowserContext browserContext = browser.newContext();
        Page page = browserContext.newPage();
        page.navigate("https://www.fdic.gov/bank-failures/failed-bank-list");
        Locator dropdown = page.locator("[id=edit-items-per-page]");
        dropdown.selectOption("All");
        page.locator("[id=edit-submit-failed-bank-list]").click();
        Locator listLocator = page.locator(".sticky-table tbody tr");
        System.out.println(listLocator.count());

What I did here is: Selected ALL in the dropdown and clicked the Apply button to see 570 banks listed, then found the locator of each bank. Somehow, this didn't print the count of list. Should I scroll down?

A quick look at that site suggests that it's taking a few seconds to return the complete list. Perhaps you should wait a while before trying to scrape the data.

Or...just use the API

You could navigate directly to https://www.fdic.gov/bank-failures/failed-bank-list?combine=&items_per_page=All (skip buttons and navs when possible if you're scraping) and use .count() with the .usa-table tr selector.
I don't have Java, but you should be able to adapt this simple JS code to Java:
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.46.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  const url = 
    "https://www.fdic.gov/bank-failures/failed-bank-list?combine=&items_per_page=All";
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "commit"});
  const sel = ".usa-table tr";
  await page.locator(sel).first().waitFor();
  console.log(await page.locator(sel).count()); // => 571
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

The data is static so there's no need for Playwright in any case, you can make an HTTP request to the URL and parse it with any static HTML parser. The table is converted to .sticky-table after load and you probably can scroll down to activate the JS, but why go through the trouble?
Better yet, use the public API: https://banks.data.fdic.gov/docs/#/Failures/getFailures

Thanks so much for your comment! But how do I use that public API to return all the failed banks in the list? I tried but it has limit integer which is not giving exact number of banks. Thanks in advance!!

This is response body when I set FAILYR:["1934" TO "2025"] up to get all the banks but it counts 4110 which is not true.
"total": 4110,
"parameters": {
"filters": "FAILYR:["1934" TO "2025"]",
"fields": "NAME,CERT,FIN,CITYST,FAILDATE,SAVR,RESTYPE,RESTYPE1,QBFDEP,QBFASSET,COST",
"limit": "10",
"offset": "0",
"aggsMetaData": {
"by": "FAILYR",
"sumFields": [
"QBFASSET",
"QBFDEP",
"COST"
],

From the page you're scraping, it says "This list includes banks, which have failed since October 1, 2000". So use that in the API call. I got 587 when I did that in their API test page, and you can then filter out months if you care about Oct 1, 2000 specifically for some reason.

curl "https://banks.data.fdic.gov/api/failures?filters=FAILYR%3A%5B%222000%22%20TO%20%222024%22%5D" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "accept: application/json" is the CURL.

Oh, great. I got 587 too. So do you think I should use that API call to retrieve 587 instead of using UI and tons of clicking? Could you please help me writing API test to retrieve 587 in the list? Thanks!!

Yes, the API is going to be way easier and faster. I don't have Java, so just plop the curl call into ChatGPT and ask it to translate to Java, or adapt something from How to send HTTP request in Java? to this call.

Cool, I'm able to translate it to Java. I really appreciate your help. Thanks so much!
